# MySQL query to count occurence of specific column value relating to id column

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering how to do a MySQL query that counts how many times a certain column value appears. For example I have a table with various columns, i'm interested in the id and prop_id columns. I want to count how many times a prop_id is 2, in relation to each id.

```
id - prop_id
1  - a
1  - b
2  - c
3  - b
3  - b
3  - c
```

The results of my query would be:

```
id - count(prop_id)
1 - 1
2 - 0
3 - 2
```

I'm having trouble translating this into a query despite it probably being fairly simple. I'm sure my terminology is off too, my knowledge of MySql is fairly basic, for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to list all the `id` values, you need to complicate your query by retrieving all ids in a subquery and left join that on your table:

```
select t.id, count(t2.id) as props_count
from (select distinct id from table) t
left join table t2 on t.id=t2.id and t2.prop_id='b'
group by t.id
```

Comment: Hey Shadow, I appreciate the response! Would you mind walking through line by line what the query is doing? I get the gist of it but I think the order than are executed is confusing me a bit.

Comment: Pls ask what's unclear rather than a complete walkthrough. I did provide an explanation to the more complex part of the query.

Comment: I figured it out! Didn't realize 'table' referred to my actual table containing all of my data >.< Once I substituted that in it worked perfectly! Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that :)